# Silverlight Unhandled Error

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am getting the following error in Silverlight for one of the users. The target runtime is 4.1.10329.0 and the application is built using Silverlight 4. I don't happen to understand what may be the issue. Looks like it is trying to load something on LoadComponent and failing:

```
Message: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application 
Parser_CreateFromValue_CannotConvertInitializationText]
Arguments: PropertyChanged,System.Windows.Data.UpdateSourceTrigger
Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide   
sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/? 
linkid=106663&Version=4.1.10329.0&File=System.Windows.dll&Key=
Parser_CreateFromValue_Cannot    ConvertInitializationText 
[Line: 582 Position: 273]    at    
System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object   component, Uri resourceLocator)
at Samplexxx.MainPage.InitializeComponent()
at Samplexxx.MainPage..ctor()
at Samplexxx.App.Application_Startup(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate  
handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs,
Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)
```

Any ideas on what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Open IIS on the server, go to HTTP headers, click on Mime Types, click “Add New” and add the following:

Extension – Mime Type
.xaml – application/xaml+xml
.xap – application/x-silverlight-app
.xbap – application/x-ms-xbap